# How to catch the event of a click on mapview in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a sliding drawer in a map view... Now i need to make this siding drawer dissappear on the click of mapview... I tried mapview.setonclick listener but it didnt worked... How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513766/android-mapview-does-not-recognize-clicks) you have to implement with the Overlay class for the map on click event see this

here is the code for implementation

```
public class MyMapActivity extends MapActivity {

class MapOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay{       
  @Override
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e, MapView mapView) {   
    if (e.getAction() == 1) {                
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext,"on click",2000).show();
    }                            
    return false;
  }        
}

  // MyMapActivity methods
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay();
    List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    listOfOverlays.clear();
    listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513766/android-mapview-does-not-recognize-clicks/13122926#13122926) I would override the `onTap` method instead of the `onTouchEvent` if you just want to have an click listener.