# How can I handle a MapView's onClick events and open the Google Maps application?

Tags: java, android, android-mapview, android-maps, android-event

I have a `MapView` in my application. I've gotten it to work as I want it to but I'd like to handle all the `onClick` or an equivalent event of the `MapView` and open the Google Maps application.

I've read that I can open the Google Maps application but raising an `Intent` like this:

```
String uri = "geo:"+ latitude + "," + longitude;
startActivity(new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri)));
```

How can I trap the aforementioned event of my `MapView`? I haven't been able to figure this out. Thanks.

Comment: See if the solution in this answer helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4513858/450534

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the `onTap` event like this:

```
public boolean onTap(GeoPoint gptLocation, MapView mapMap) {

    String strCoordinates = String.format("%f,%f", gptCoordinates.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6, gptCoordinates.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6);
    String strUri = String.format("geo:%s?z=14", strCoordinates);
    Intent ittMap = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(strUri));
    ittMap.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    this.ctxContext.startActivity(ittMap);
    return false;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have a class that extends `com.google.android.maps.Overlay` in your activity and use this class' `onTouchEvent()` method. Like this:

```
class MyOverlay extends Overlay {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e, MapView mapView) {
         ....
    }
    ....
}
```

Comment: I tried this but I still can't seem to get the touch/click events. I has a custom `Overlay` which I was using to draw a custom marker onto the map. I added the method you mentioned into my custom `Overlay` class but it didn't work. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does your Activity extends MapActivity?

Comment: yes it does. I even tried removing the `draw()` method from my `Overlay` class but that didn't help. I'm wondering if it is some issue with the layout and some other control e.g. a `Button` is stealing the focus and touch events. I've read about this kind of issue somewhere. Any ideas?